# Changing text and setting a default

Tags: javascript, angular

This is my common Angular component "messageforStudents".

messageforStudents.html:

```
<span>{{firstText}}</span>
<span>{{secondText}}</span>
```

messageforStudents.ts:

```
firstText = "Default text 1.";
secondText = "Default text 2.";
```

I will be using the above component everywhere with that text.

But when I use the `messageforStudents` component inside `schoolRules.html` I want to chnage the text of `<span>{{firstText}}</span>` and `<span>{{secondText}}</span>`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [@Input](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) in angular.

Something like this

```js
@Input firstText = "Default text 1.";
@Input secondText = "Default text 2.";
```

And then use the component

```html
<MessageforStudents [firstText]="foo" [secondText]="bar"></MessageforStudents>
```

If you don't pass `firstText` or `secondText` it'll take the default value you have set.

Answer (score 1):

By using input properties you can pass the data like below.

**messageForStudents.ts**

```
@Input() firstText = "Default text 1.";
@Input() secondText = "Default text 2.";
```

**schoolRules.component.html**

```
<message-students [firstTest]="changedValueFirst" [secondText]="changedValueSecond"></message-students>
```

**schoolRules.component.ts**

```
changedValueFirst="Custom String 1";
changedValueSecond= "Custom String 1";
```

**In Other components use it like :-**

```
<message-students></message-students>
```

Comment: A part of your solution helped me. Thank you! +10

Answer (score 0):

Decorate `firstText = "Default text 1.";` variable with an @Input decorator;

```
@Input() firstText = "Default text 1.";

<messageforStudents [firstText]="any other text"></messageforStudents>
```

You can do this similary for secondText;

If you dont pass any values as input `<messageforStudents></messageforStudents>`, it will fall back to default text you assigned in the component i.e `"Default text 1."` and show that instead