# How to transfer variables from a ts fie to another, angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic4

I defined a property here in my function

```
evs: string
...
openArticle(url){
    this.evs = url
    console.log(this.evs)
    this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/url-page')

  }
```

And I a trying to pass the value of 'this.evs' to another ts file and use its value but I do not know how to do this. I tried exporting it like this.

```
export const webpage = this.evs
```

but this.evs has no value until someone performs the openArticle function ad so I keep getting the error. "Cannot read property 'evs' of undefined"

What i need to do is tranfer the variable to the 'url-page' page and use the value of this.evs only after the openArticle function has bee called. How do I go about this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing text and setting a default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62062889/changing-text-and-setting-a-default)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62062889/changing-text-and-setting-a-default/62063122?noredirect=1#comment109774860_62063122

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you are trying to share data between two components.
So choose one of them as per your requirements.

1. Parent to Child: Sharing Data via Input().
2. Child to Parent: Sharing Data via Output() and EventEmitter.
3. Unrelated Components: Sharing Data with a Service.

[This link will be helpful](https://medium.com/@nodexperts_88267/data-transfer-one-component-to-another-angular-7-c076272c78e1).

Answer (score 0):

1. If the components have a parent/child relationship, You can share data between them via @Inpput() and @Output() decorators.

Sharing data from Parent to Child using @Input() :

```
<h3>Parent Component</h3>

<label>Parent Component</label>c
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]='parentValue'/>

<p>Value of child component is: </p>
<app-child [value]='parentValue'></app-child>
```

And in the child component, the 'parentValue' can be received as :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() value: number;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Now, in the case of sending data from Child to Parent, we can use an @Output() event emitter. So the parent would have a function to receive the emitted data from child as :

```
parent-app.component.html 
    <app-child [value]="parentValue" (childEvent)="childEvent($event)"></app-child>

parent-app.component.ts

childEvent(event) {
console.log(event);
}

And, the child.component.ts would look like :

import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() PData: number;
  @Output() childEvent = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() { }
  onChange(value) {
    this.childEvent.emit(value);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

1. If the components do not have a parent/child relationship, a shared service can be used, say, SharedService which has a BehavioralSubject, that emits value from either component, and the other component can then catch the changed value.

Eg:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs/BehaviorSubject";

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  comp1Val: string;
  _comp1ValueBS = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

  comp2Val: string;
  _comp2ValueBS = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

  constructor() {
    this.comp1Val;
    this.comp2Val;

    this._comp1ValueBS.next(this.comp1Val);
    this._comp2ValueBS.next(this.comp2Val);
  }

  updateComp1Val(val) {
    this.comp1Val = val;
    this._comp1ValueBS.next(this.comp1Val);
  }

  updateComp2Val(val) {
    this.comp2Val = val;
    this._comp2ValueBS.next(this.comp2Val);
  }
```

And component1 as follows :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs/BehaviorSubject";

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  comp1Val: string;
  _comp1ValueBS = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

  comp2Val: string;
  _comp2ValueBS = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

  constructor() {
    this.comp1Val;
    this.comp2Val;

    this._comp1ValueBS.next(this.comp1Val);
    this._comp2ValueBS.next(this.comp2Val);
  }

  updateComp1Val(val) {
    this.comp1Val = val;
    this._comp1ValueBS.next(this.comp1Val);
  }

  updateComp2Val(val) {
    this.comp2Val = val;
    this._comp2ValueBS.next(this.comp2Val);
  }
```

Component 2 :

```
import { Component, AfterContentChecked } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from "../../common/shared.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component2',
  templateUrl: './component2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component2.component.css']
})
export class Component2Component implements AfterContentChecked {

  comp1Val: string;
  comp2Val: string;

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {
    this.sharedService.comp2Val = "Component 2 initial value";
  }

  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    this.comp1Val = this.sharedService.comp1Val;
  }

  addValue(str) {
    this.sharedService.updateComp2Val(str);
  }

}
```

You can find more on different types of subjects [here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject)

Comment: I  need to transfer the value of evs from a ts file to another seperate ts file in different pages but the same project. I am using ionic to create this app and I have two totally different pages and I need to transfer the value of env from the ts file of one page to the ts file of another page. @Gauri Kesava Kumar

Comment: Please see of this would answer your question. We can pass Navigationextras as parameters, so you can pass your this.evs along with the navigateForward method : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-pass-data-from-1-page-to-another-using-navigation-in-ionic-4/151060/2